# Angular 2 (2.0.0 to 2.2.0~) getting error while adding custom decorator with the line "import 'reflect-metadata'"

Tags: angular, typescript, annotations, decorator, reflect-metadata

On my project base on **gulp** I was trying to implement a custom decorator for data validation but at a point I got stuck because of this error:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginService: (?, ?, ?).(…)
```

Or an error like this in other cases:

```
Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

Then I started to do some tests and I found out that line causing this error is:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

Here are two versions of the tour-of-heroes tutorial:

[With the error caused by importing reflect-metadata.](http://plnkr.co/edit/cE15NUZbuuLwnSdyy0Uq?p=preview)

[And with the solution.](http://plnkr.co/edit/O6IQvhJQeZccfBrMkB8o?p=preview)

**EDIT**

I've edited the title by adding the versions of angular which i'm sure this fix works, from version 1.3.0 i'm having trouble using decorators and that's why i'm moving my project from gulp to webpack

Comment: Those errors don't sound like it has anything to do with the decorator. Are you saying that everything works when you don't use the decorator? If so, did you install `reflect-metadata` into the project?

Comment: yes, everything works fine if i remove the decorator, by eliminating the @Validate the application load correctly...
I've downloaded the tour-of.heroes without edit anything and actually i also tried to look if newer version of angular run correctly but with version 2.1.0-beta.0 i still have this issue.
And yes, `reflect-metadata: ^0.1.3` is already in the package.json of the tour-of-heroes project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a day debugging angular and editing my code I found the solution to this issue only by adding another import **on top of all other imports**:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

to the class that is mentioned in the error even if the class isn't using any object of reflect-metadata:

e.g.
If you are getting an error like these:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginService: (?, ?, ?).(…)
```

Or

```
Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

Add the import line to the classes LoginService and AppComponent to solve the issue.

[Here is a working version on Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/O6IQvhJQeZccfBrMkB8o?p=preview)

**EDIT**

I've edited the title by adding the versions of angular which i'm sure this fix works, from version 1.3.0 i'm having trouble using decorators and that's why i'm moving my project from gulp to webpack

Comment: This saved my day

Comment: I had the same issue, important side note from me, is to add the import above all other imports in app.module.ts or whatever your module file is named.

Answer (score 2):

Building off Lemmy4555's answer (I don't have the rep to comment), I was able to fix this by adding

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

to my main angular module.  I can't yet explain exactly what is going wrong, but by importing the library elsewhere it seems that a wrench is thrown in angular's decorators and dependency injection doesn't work right.

It's not an ideal solution, but IMO it's cleaner than importing it where errors pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error in console

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for XXX: (?, ?, ?)

and i found a solution with provide my services on NgModule
look my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721884/inject-custom-provider-in-angular-2-0-1)

i hope to help you.

Comment: The error is raised when i use the import reflect-metadata. Anyway i've tried your solution by adding this line `{ provide:"appLoginService", useClass: LoginService },` and edited the injection points like this: `@Inject('appLoginService') private loginService: LoginService`.I still have the error

Comment: Ok i will try make an example in plunker in some hour and paste here if i found the solution.

Comment: i don't understand why you want do this but it's look like work in my example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9jx3TQqHwy9kAlMV7yoD?p=preview).
i put a debugger on setter in decoration and stop there.
if you explain more what do you want to do maybe help you with some other example.

Comment: I'll try to do the same things after removing all services from my actual project, maybe the problem is one of the services.

Comment: It looks like in some cases (like mine) the constructor of the class Reflect.ts is called twice on startup, this cause lose informations that Angular require to read a Component's decorator: @Component...

Comment: i hope to help you with my example or just send me or do in plunker some example of your code to help you more.

Comment: Here is it, i've added the Decorator Validate in hero-detail.component: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cE15NUZbuuLwnSdyy0Uq?p=preview)

Comment: That's really strange, the example l gave you raise an error on AppComponent, only by adding `import "reflect-metadata";` on this component solved the issue and now everything is working fine....

Comment: [Here is the working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/O6IQvhJQeZccfBrMkB8o?p=preview)

Comment: Nice @Lemmy4555. If you have more problems let us know. Enjoy your coding. :)

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the similar error (`Unexpected value 'XXX' declared by the module 'AppModule'`) by removing the `import 'reflect-metadata';` statement and installing typings for `Reflect` by `npm install @types/reflect-metadata --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Another option that works for me is to use Reflect as a global variable, without importing reflect-metadata at all

Something like

`declare const global: any;
const Reflect = global['Reflect'];`

Reference https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d