# Error: No provider for ShopService! Using a service in another service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

EDIT: a lot of this question was deleted as it became less relevant as I found out more about the problem.

I get this error in the console:

> Error in app/find-page/find-page.component.html:1:3 caused by: No
>   provider for ShopService!

The place where I use ShopService is in another Service called ResultService. How do I declare a provider for ShopService in ResultService? Because when I add ShopService to the providers of the only module in the app (appModule), it says no provider for ShopService.

Is this because ResultService is not declared in appModule, causing the provider in appModule not to work for ResultService? Where would I declare it in AppModule? Because I added it to the declarations of appModule I got:

> find:21 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'ResultService' declared by
>   the module 'AppModule'(…)

code:

ResultService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Result } from '../result';
import { RESULTS } from '../mock-results';
import { ShopService } from './shop.service';

@Injectable()
export class ResultService {

constructor(private shopService: ShopService) {}

  getResults(): Result[] {
    RESULTS.forEach(result => {
      result.nearbyShops = this.shopService.getShops();
    });
    return RESULTS;
  }
}
```

ShopService:

```
import { Shop } from '../result';
import { SHOPS } from '../mock-shops';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ShopService {
  getShops(): Shop[] {
    return SHOPS;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you might purge your `node_modules` folder and start over.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks, I did that and have posted the results in my question.

Comment: Could you post your find-page.component ?

Comment: @Outlooker yes have done that thanks

Comment: shouldn't u be initializing the service inside the constructor of FindPageComponent ? like `constructor(private shopService: ShopService) {

    }`

Comment: @Outlooker I just posted my usage of shopService in the bottom of the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error with yours

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for services: (?, ?, ?)

and i found a solution with provide my services on NgModule
look my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721884/inject-custom-provider-in-angular-2-0-1)

i hope to help you.

Comment: There is a red error line under `@Injectable` and `@Inject` for me.

Comment: are you import in from '@angular2/core'? could you send me some plunker or sample?

Comment: Yes. Strangely, the red error lines have disappeared now. I will try your answer again.

Comment: I tried again and I have the same error as my question is about. I posted my attempt at implementing your solution at the bottom of my question. Please let me know if I did it wrong. Thanks.

Comment: ok, i will see at the evening because now i am at work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue -
My "MenuService" depends on a "SecurityService".
I provided both services in the AppModule, but as soon as my MenuService was created, I got the error "No provider for SecurityService".

I know for sure the SecurityService exists because I could log it out on the console.

Note* - Both of these service definitions are imported from external npm packages, because I want to use them in other projects. So this could have an impact on the root cause.

The only solution for me, was to create a MenuServiceFactory to provide the MenuService and pass in the SecurityService to the constructor.

Example test case -

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
import { provideRoutes } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { SecurityModule, SecurityService } from '@savantly/ngx-security';
import { MenuModule, MenuService } from '@savantly/ngx-menu';


const menuServiceFactory = (_securityService: SecurityService) => {
  return new MenuService(_securityService);
};

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, SecurityModule.forRoot(), MenuModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MenuService,
          useFactory: menuServiceFactory,
          deps: [SecurityService]
        },
        provideRoutes([])
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

You can also move this factory into the original module if you want consumers to have it easier -

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, SkipSelf, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';
import { MenuService } from './menu.service';
import { MdMenuModule, MdToolbarModule, MdButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { SecurityModule, SecurityService } from '@savantly/ngx-security';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MdMenuModule, MdToolbarModule, MdButtonModule, FlexLayoutModule, SecurityModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    MdMenuModule, MdToolbarModule, MdButtonModule, FlexLayoutModule,
    SecurityModule,
    MenuComponent],
  declarations: [MenuComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class MenuModule {

  static forRoot({securityService = SecurityService}: {securityService?: SecurityService} = {}): ModuleWithProviders {
     return {
        ngModule: MenuModule,
        providers: [{
            provide: MenuService,
            useFactory: menuServiceFactory,
            deps: [securityService]
          }]
      };
  }

  constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: MenuModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'MenuModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }
 }

export function menuServiceFactory(_securityService: SecurityService): MenuService {
  return new MenuService(_securityService);
}
```

References -
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#factory-providers
https://github.com/savantly-net/sprout-platform